# CS50 Readability: Why is my code not accepting my string?

Tags: c, cs50

I don't know what's wrong with my code. When I run it the (get_string("Text: ");) won't accept anything and I have to ctrl c to get out of it. I'm a beginner it's my second time coding in C, so please tell me if I have missed something important. Also, if you have any tips that can make my code look better, thank you!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int letters(string a)
float words(string b)
int sentences(string c)

int main(void)
{
    // Prompt user
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    //L is the average number of letters per 100 words in the text
    float L = (letters(text) / words(text)) * 100;
    //S is the average number of sentences per 100 words in the text
    float S = (sentences(text) / words(text)) * 100;

    float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;

    //int grade = index round
    int grade = (index);

    //printing out grade level
    if (grade < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1");
    }
    else if (grade > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", grade);
    }

}

    //letters function that counts letters in string text
int letters(string a)
{
    int lettercount = 0;
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(a); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(a[i]))
        {
            lettercount++;
        }
    }
    return lettercount;
}

    //words function that counts spaces in string text
float words(string b)
{
    int wordcount = 1;
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(b); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isspace(b[i]))
        {
            wordcount++;
        }
    }
    return wordcount;
}

    //sentences function that counts exclamation points and full stops in string text
int sentences(string c)
{
    int sentencecount = 0;
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(c); i < n; i++)
    {
         while ((c[i] == '.') || (c[i] == '!') || (c[i] == '?'))
        {
        sentencecount++;
        }
    }
    return sentencecount;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `int letters(string a)` --> `int letters(string a);` you miss the semicolon in all your prototypes

Comment: "When I run it..." Well, you can't **run** this code as it can't compile. Did you post the wrong code? Or is it your system (compiler, IDE, etc) that requires you to press ctrl-c after a compiler error?

Comment: Apart from needing to correctly terminate your function prototypes for `letters()`, `words()` and `sentences()`, we can't help you without the function definition for `get_string()`.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson in CS50, `string` is a `typedef` of `char *` and `get_string (const string prompt);` will read and allocate for the input returning a pointer to the allocated string. See [CS50 on github](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50) (it's actuall `get_string (va_list *args, const char *format, ...)` -- but for all practical purposes -- it takes the prompt as the 1st argument).

Comment: Instead of computing the length of the string and iterating with `for(int i = 0, n = strlen(a); i < n; i++) {...}`, it is more idiomatic to write `for(int i=0; a[i]; i++)`.  It is even more idiomatic to write `for( ; *a; a++)`

Comment: Also, just what do you think **Ctrl + C** does in Linux? (hint: `Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.`)

Answer (score 0):

I pulled down the source for the cs50 library, and built your code:

```
nuudly:cs50 $ cc -fPIC libcs50/src/cs50.c test.c  -o cs50test
nuudly:cs50 $ ./cs50test
Text: test
Grade 7
nuudly:cs50 $ ./cs50test
Text: does this work?
^C
nuudly:cs50 $
nuudly:cs50 $ ./cs50test
Text: no it does not
Before Grade 1  nuudly:cs50 $
```

As you can see, entering the question mark prevented the function from completing.

Recompiling with `-g` (and `-Og` for good measure) we can see where this is failing by running under GDB:

```
$ cc -g -Og -fPIC libcs50/src/cs50.c test.c  -o cs50test
$ gdb ./cs50test

(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/cs50/cs50test
Text: Does this work?
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x0000555555555f45 in sentences (c=c@entry=0x55555555a6b0 "Does this work?") at test.c:76
76           while ((c[i] == '.') || (c[i] == '!') || (c[i] == '?'))
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000555555555f45 in sentences (c=c@entry=0x55555555a6b0 "Does this work?") at test.c:76
#1  0x0000555555555fb3 in main () at test.c:19
```

Can you see your logic error on line 76 in `sentences()`  ?